# How to compile one Kotlin class before codegeneration task in Gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin, compilation, task

I have gradle task that fulfills code generation from XSD to java by jaxb. But code generation needs one handmade annotation class (written on  Kotlin) what is put in source directory of project. How can I compile and put in classpath just one this file before code generation task?

in gradle project I have this lines:

```
configurations {
  jaxb
}
```

So in code generation task I pass as param configurations.jaxb.asPath
I suggest that compiled class must be included in this classpath

It have to be compilation of only this one file, not of whole project, because code generation not yet completed for this moment and needed classes are not created.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to either call the compiler manually (tricky) or simply put that annotation in a subproject and then `dependencies { jaxb project(':handmade-annotations') }`

The subproject will likely need to be a `` plugins { id `java-library` } `` + usual Kotlin setup.

Alternatively you can create a small separate project in the same repo, build the jar and version-control it as `libs/handmade-annotations.jar` or something, but I think building it from source when necessary is better.